SQL Connection With Domain Account Impersonate Error
I am trying to connect to my SQL 2019 Database with a Domain level account used for a software. The SQL Server is joined to the domain. I am trying to connect to it on the local server. My Account and the Domain account have been added into the Security/users section of the server and the database. Connection to the database is a secure connection. I can connect without a problem with my domain\user account but the Domain level account can't. I even gave it the same permissions I have but still it can not connect with an error which says:

MS SQL Win Logon - impersonate required with custom user id,password.
Get connection failed by impersonation.

This DOMAIN\Account is a service account and is blocked by GPO to logon locally so launching SSMS is not an option as a different user. Is there some other log or some way to find out why I can connect but this user account can not?

This issue turned out to be an issue outside of SQL itself. This was found to be the case by when connections into SQL that were attempted were not logged by SQL as the access was being blocked at the server level due to security settings on the server. The server was configured to limit who can access the computer locally using User Rights Assignment. Also the method of connection to the SQL server was also part of the problem as this service account was being used by the software through the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL. The other software that accessing SQL did not use this driver which is why the others worked. The service account needed to be out of the groups that were prevented from logging in locally in the User Rights Assignment. The service account needed to be able to outside of the "Deny logon locally" User Rights Assignment as it needed to make an interactive logon on the machine to access the ODBC driver to get into SQL. I have done some mitigation to prevent it from actually logging in locally to meet the intent and connections are now made.
